# Different types of string in one guitar

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, strings

2 months ago, I bought D'Addario strings with specification:

1. 80/20 bronze
2. EJ10
3. Extra light gauge 0.010-0.047

And then my G-string broke and I bought a new set

1. Phosphor bronze
2. EJ16
3. Light gauge 0.012-0.053

I changed only the G-string with the new one. But I am finding it difficult to tune it to other strings both manually and with help of tuners.
Even when the tuner shows perfect G, I can feel it simply doesn't sound right. I can not explain but something is there.

Shall I change the whole set or there maybe other reasons?

Comment: Phosphor Bronze has a different sound than 80/20 Bronze.  80/20 Bronze sounds brighter.  You can buy individual D'Addario strings from JustStrings.com  I buy extra G strings to keep in my guitar case because the G string is the one that breaks most often.  It has the thinnest core (the part that withstands tension) of any the other strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your new set has higher gauge than the old one. If you mix strings at different gauges, they might sound differently.

Moreover, after two months the old strings might be simply worn, and sound badly, or even out of tune. I would suggest changing all 6 strings at a time.

Finally, if you change the string gauge you'll likely need to set up the guitar again, in particular adjust the truss rod.

Comment: If I change all 6 strings together, do I have to adjust the truss rod? I have never adjusted that. And can you clarify what exactly you mean by 'adjust'?

Comment: @banikr if you put 6 new strings with a higher tension, the neck will bend more – possibly too much. You can compensate this with the truss rod screw. If you don't know how to do it, better look up instructions before you start, or let a guitar tech take care of this. There is a chance of damaging the guitar if you turn the truss rod screw too much

Comment: Thanks all. I dont know why the G string of light gauge broke in just 2-3 days. I will probably get the same spec strings again. Are there better alternatives than D'Addario for 0.010-0.047 extra light gauge?

Answer (score 1):

The new string is heavier than the original G, so will have more tension. This, combined with the fact that it's new while the others have settled, giving it a different tone, particularly from the bottom three, will make it sound different.

The tuning issue may well be because it's a new string. New strings take a while to settle in. If you do nothing but tune and play, in a few weeks, you'll find it's blended in, usually.

The idea of a *set* of strings is that they're matched to each other, all with approximately the same tension. That's now out of balance a little, and when you put the rest on, there will be more tension on the neck, given they make a heavier gauge set. Not a tremendous difference, but possibly enough to make the action higher. That, coupled with the tighter strings will make the guitar not so pleasant to play. Adjusting the trussrod, as user1079505 suggests, will pull the neck straighter, by tightening the trussrod by maybe 1/4 or 1/2 a turn. Not a recommended job for someone who's not experienced.

I have no idea why you have a heavier set of strings, but if you're happy with the feel of the old set, keep to that gauge, it'll save touching the trussrod.

Comment: I bought heavier strings because the old string broke just after 2-3 days of playing. So I thought the strings are too light for the guitar tension and purchased heavier strings.

Comment: Heavier strings = tighter strings = more propensity to breakage.